# How do I restart the plasma shell in KDE5?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-workspace

I want to restart my plasma desktop/shell without rebooting my machine and was looking for a way to do so. Is there some konsole command or something that would do just that?

Answer (score 34):

So I think I found an answer. Modifing the KDE 4 command from [humbug.in](http://www.humbug.in/2010/killquit-and-restart-plasma-on-kde/) like so:

```
kbuildsycoca5 && kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
```

Comment: The kbuildsycoca5 portion is unnecessary, the simplest way to do it is using kquitapp5 for Plasma 5. http://askubuntu.com/a/663702/72652 (best done in KRunner rather than in a terminal)

Comment: `pkill plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell` works

Answer (score 21):

Kill `plasmashell` and start it in the background.

```
killall plasmashell
plasmashell > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Comment: This is fine as long as you don't mind `plasmashell` spewing a bunch of logging information to your terminal.  You also won't be able to close the terminal, or else the plasma shell will be killed.  Better to use `kstart5 plasmashell` as someone else suggested.

Comment: @Psychonaut While `kstart5` would be the more "correct" solution, plasmashell would not be killed as a result of closing the terminal as we start it in the background.

Comment: Putting the process in the background has no effect unless you also disown it. It will be killed along with its parent terminal.

Comment: @Psychonaut Ah, right, of course. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: `sh: disown: not found` but the line had the required effect; I can then exit from all Konsole windows and `plasmashell` continues to run. `FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #0 r320869: Mon Jul 10 13:57:55 UTC 2017     root@releng3.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC`

Answer (score 6):

For Plasma 5.27+

```
plasmashell --replace & disown
```

Now you can close konsole.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having trouble with KDE right now. Sometimes it boots in a black screen, no nothing.

But if you type `ALT+F2` and open up a `konsole`, you can see KDE is just running fine without `plasmashell`. No `plasmashell` in the process table, no need to kill it. In my case, just typing:

```
kstart5 plasmashell
```

will solve the case.

Also, no need to tell it to go on background (or disown it), because it will do just that anyway. You can close the `konsole` and it will keep running just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I am running plasmashell 5.26.4 and the easiest way to restart it is

```
plasmashell --replace &
```

Comment: This is the best solution for recent systems. Thank you.

Comment: But if I close the terminal, plasmashell goes down. Plasma version 5.26.5

Comment: **@shmu** Did you forget the `&` at the end of the command? For me it works even if I close the terminal

Comment: @shmu, try to add `disown` at the end

Answer (score -1):

In Debian 8 it's:

`killall plasma-desktop && plasma-desktop`

to restart