# KDE 5 - Plasma keeps crashing and not starting again (no task bar, no right clicking desktop)

Tags: taskbar, kde, kde-plasma-workspace, kde-plasma-5

I have a problem like [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/946206/kde-plasma-5-no-taskbar-and-cant-right-click-desktop): After booting I come into a desktop w/o taskbar and where the desktop is not reacting to right click. Most of the times krunner works, so I can start programs (Ctrl+Alt+T opens a terminal as well, moving the cursor to the top left corner shows all current windows, I can switch between virtual desktops by shortcuts). I deleted `.config/plasma*`, `.kde4/` and even created a new user, but nothing seems to help with the problem. When logging in, KDE is loading, but the splash screen hangs for several seconds at the end, before showing the desktop. Oddly, there *is* an artefact of the taskbar on the lower left screen corner, which is about 1px wide and has the height of the taskbar (and also the slight "glare" around it).

I tried restarting it manually with `kstart plasma-shell` which gives me
`kstart(1597) main: Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended`. Running `kquitapp plasma-shell` beforehand just hangs.

I have this issue since updating from KDE 4 -> 5. A few times it resolved itself or I could resolve it by deleting above mentioned folders, but mostly it didn't help. When it is working, the issue reappears either for example when I take out/plug in my laptop to the docking station by crashing `plasma-shell` (it asks me to report a but then, which it declines because of too few information) and clicking restart doesn't work.

Any hints about how to resolve this or where to look at (`journalctl` gives me no errors) would be greatly appreciated. I'm running Arch Linux on a Lenovo T410 (Intel HD graphics).

**EDIT**

Here the console output from one of the few times where I could restart plasmashell from the konsole (got the background image that way, but still no taskbar). The last lines are repeated on and on (a few of them per second)

```
[johannes@XX ~]$ kstart plasmashell
kstart(1934) main: Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 72 , Name: "HDMI3" ) ( "HDMI3" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 72 , Name: "HDMI3" ) ( "HDMI3" )
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/usr/share/wallpapers/Colorado_Farm/contents/images//metadata.desktop"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/usr/share/wallpapers/Colorado_Farm/contents/images//metadata.desktop"
No metadata file in the package, expected it at: "/usr/share/wallpapers/Colorado_Farm/contents/images//metadata.desktop"
kscreen: Primary output changed from KScreen::Output(Id: 72 , Name: "HDMI3" ) ( "HDMI3" ) to KScreen::Output(Id: 72 , Name: "HDMI3" ) ( "HDMI3" )
Known plasmoid ids: QHash()
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
unversioned plugin detected, may result in instability
org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: Attempting connection to PulseAudio sound daemon
org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: QHash((263, "Muted")(260, "Index")(261, "Properties")(266, "Name")(267, "Description")(264, "HasVolume")(265, "VolumeWritable")(270, "ActivePortIndex")(268, "CardIndex")(269, "Ports")(258, "PulseObject")(259, "ObjectName")(257, "Index")(262, "Volume"))
org.kde.plasma.pulseaudio: QHash((263, "Muted")(260, "Index")(261, "Properties")(266, "Name")(267, "Description")(264, "HasVolume")(265, "VolumeWritable")(270, "ActivePortIndex")(268, "CardIndex")(269, "Ports")(258, "PulseObject")(259, "ObjectName")(257, "Index")(262, "Volume"))
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/plasma/extras/ScrollArea.qml:48: Error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "interactive"
Notifications service registered
file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/Notifications.qml:135: TypeError: Cannot read property 'IdleTime' of undefined
XSync seems available and ready
XSync Inited
Supported, init completed
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:96: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:96: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:37: TypeError: Cannot read property 'flat' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:38: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hovered' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:124: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml:83: TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:37: TypeError: Cannot read property 'flat' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:38: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hovered' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:124: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml:83: TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:37: TypeError: Cannot read property 'flat' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:38: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hovered' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:124: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml:83: TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:96: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:96: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:37: TypeError: Cannot read property 'flat' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:38: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hovered' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:124: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml:83: TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:37: TypeError: Cannot read property 'flat' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:38: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hovered' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:124: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml:83: TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:96: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Button.qml:96: TypeError: Cannot read property of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:37: TypeError: Cannot read property 'flat' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:38: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hovered' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Plasma/ToolButtonStyle.qml:124: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
file:///usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml:83: TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of null
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 1025 Forbidden
libkcups: Calling cupsDoAuthentication() password_retries: 0
libkcups: Called cupsDoAuthentication(), success: true
libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 1025 Forbidden
libkcups: Calling cupsDoAuthentication() password_retries: 0
libkcups: Called cupsDoAuthentication(), success: true
```

until some 15 Minutes later or so the taskbar did appear with

```
libkcups: Calling cupsDoAuthentication() password_retries: 0
libkcups: Called cupsDoAuthentication(), success: true
Plasma Shell startup completed
```

but the libkcups messages go on and on.

Comment: I would start by disabling your display manager (I presume lightdm, as I run the same config), so you can log in via the virtual tty. Then, starting kde on CLI (startkde) ought to give you some useful error messages. However, the Arch Linux wiki, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE, warns that **The Plasma 4 configuration is not automatically migrated to Plasma 5, so you will have to configure your desktop from scratch.**. Might this be your problem?

Comment: Since I already deleted the config a few times I had to reconfigure already. Also a newly created user should not suffer from configuration issues I'd say. I'll try starting from CLI though

Comment: I disabled cupsd and removed the printer-thingy from the system tray, so the kde printer manager isn't started in the background. That stopped the nasty libkcups messages and for now I'm getting a working desktop (with startkde as well as when booting into lightdm). I'll come back with more logs/info the next time it stops working (though I hope it will never ever do that again ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to a bug in libkcups. It will just retry to create a printer subscription until infinity, even if the user does not have that privilege granted on the cups server.

If you are using your local cups server, take a look at your `cupsd.conf` file.
It might be a good idea to reset it to the default configuration using the web interface. You can use the url http://localhost:631/admin/, select "Edit Configuration File", then "Use Default Configuration File".

If you are using a remote cups server, take a look at your `client.conf` file.
For the time being, commenting out the servers in this file will suffice to get your plasmashell back to life.
You will have to contact the server admin to grant you the necessary privileges if you want to continue using it with the KDE plugin.

Remember to restart the `org.cups.cupsd.service` daemon after changing those files to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting to default configuration file did not work. RSS subscriptions reappeared on each kstart plasmashell invocation and caused the crash. Disabling cups let the plasmashell load and then it is just the matter of removing the printer from the panel system widget.

Summary

```
$ sudo service cups stop
$ kstart plasmashell
```