# KDE panel disappeared, can't right-click, and window lag

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

When I turned on my Manjaro KDE desktop today, the panel/taskbar has completely disappeared and I cannot right-click the desktop.  I am still able to run Yakuke so that I am able to access a terminal, but when I run applications from it, they have the kind of lag that leaves behind dozens of copies of the same window.  When I close the window, it stays on the screen.

I have updated my system with `pacman` and tried several solutions online, including a [similar yet old superuser post (who's contributors are no longer active)](https://superuser.com/questions/946206/kde-plasma-5-no-taskbar-and-cant-right-click-desktop), though none of the solutions worked for me.  I am happy to provide any additional output if necessary.

Here is the output when I run `plasmashell` from the terminal:

```
$ plasmashell  Icon theme "ubuntu-mono-dark" not found. invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kfileaudiopreview.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/jpegthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/icon_mode.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_shell.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/fileviewdropboxplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/djvuthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdeconnect_runcommand_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/rawthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/gsthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/imagethumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_clock.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevilwirelesspowersavingaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_nic.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_hotkeys.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/fileviewbazaarplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/opendocumentthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_dolphinviewmodes.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kio_fonts.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kritathumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_ssl.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_plasma-desktop.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kscreen.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_sddm.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/attica_kde.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_converter.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_plasmasearch.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/sambausershareplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kio_msits.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_desktoppaths.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_locations.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcmspellchecking.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/gvpart.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_spellcheck.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_smserver.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kwallet5.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kdeconnect.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/comicbookthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/windowsexethumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_systemd.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_kill.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/windowsimagethumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_standard_actions.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_style.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_keys.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_opengl.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/fontthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/exrthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/textthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kwincompositing.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_datetime.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_view1394.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_pci.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_baloofile.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevildimdisplayaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_webshortcuts.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/libkcm_device_automounter.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_fontinst.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_bookmarksrunner.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kded_touchpad.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_emoticons.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_webshortcuts.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/user_manager.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_autostart.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_memory.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_trash.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevilkeyboardbrightnesscontrolaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kget_metalinkfactory.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/msm_timedate.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kfontviewpart.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kstyle_oxygen_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdeconnect_pausemusic_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_keyboard.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/svgthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kded_printmanager.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_services.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/appimagethumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/msm_locale.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kstyle_breeze_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_konsoleprofiles.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_powerdevilglobalconfig.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_networkmanagement.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevildpmsaction.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_dolphingeneral.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kio_obexftp.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kio_bluetooth.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdeconnect_share_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_krunner_spellcheck.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/msm_kernel.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_recentdocuments.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_about_distro.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevildpmsaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_solid_actions.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_charrunner.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_windowedwidgets.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_printer_manager.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_info.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_samba.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kgamma.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/plasma-geolocation-gps.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_sessions.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/msm_language_packages.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_activities.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_joystick.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/ffmpegthumbs.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/okularpart.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/ebookthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_dictionary.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kget_browser_integration.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/dolphinpart.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_powerdevil.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/plasma-geolocation-ip.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kget_mmsfactory.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevilhandlebuttoneventsaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kwintabbox.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdeconnect_sendnotifications_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/fileviewsvnplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kwinoptions.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/libkcm_qtquicksettings.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_katesessions.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/mltpreview.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_usb.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_phonon.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevilbrightnesscontrolaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_krunner_kill.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/blenderthumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_krunner_charrunner.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_mouse.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kamera.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_powerdevilprofilesconfig.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdeconnectfileitemaction.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_powerdevilactivitiesconfig.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kio.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/libplasmanetworkmanagement_openconnectui.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_filetypes.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevilsuspendsessionaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kded.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kget_multisegkiofactory.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kstyle_qtcurve5_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/fileviewhgplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kwin_scripts.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/miloutextplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/baloofilepropertiesplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/msm_keyboard.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/audiothumbnail.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/fileviewgitplugin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_calculatorrunner.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_windows.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/msm_mhwd.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_kwin.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/powerdevilrunscriptaction_config.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_appstream.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kwinrules.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_krunner_dictionary.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_componentchooser.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_access.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kwinscreenedges.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_dolphinnavigation.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/classic_mode.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/systemsettings_sidebar_mode.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_activities.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/msm_users.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kget_checksumsearchfactory.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_devinfo.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kget_mirrorsearchfactory.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/krunner_placesrunner.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kwintouchscreen.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_kget_bittorrentfactory.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kio_kamera.so" invalid metadata "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kcm_dolphinservices.so" org.kde.plasmaquick: Applet preload policy set to 1 file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:71:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QStringList file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:71:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QStringList trying to show an empty dialog file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height" file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height" file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:71:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QStringList file:///usr/share/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.image/contents/ui/main.qml:71:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QStringList trying to show an empty dialog file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height" file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:146:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height" file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:302:17: QML QQuickText: Binding loop detected for property "width" file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:302:17: QML QQuickText: Binding loop detected for property "width" file:///usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.desktopcontainment/contents/ui/FolderItemDelegate.qml:302:17: QML QQuickText: Binding loop detected for property "width" Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString) Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size. Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size. Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size. trying to show an empty dialog trying to show an empty dialog libkcups: CUPS-Get-Printers last error: 0 successful-ok libkcups: Create-Printer-Subscriptions last error: 0 successful-ok libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok libkcups: Get-Jobs last error: 0 successful-ok Plasma Shell startup completed libkcups: 3 "Brother_MFC-J285DW" libkcups: 5 "Canon_MG5500_series" libkcups: 3 KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/bin/plasmashell from kdeinit sock_file=/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0 QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 8 and type 'Read', disabling... QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 9 and type 'Read', disabling... QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket 51 and type 'Read', disabling... KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2 KCrash: Application Name = plasmashell path = /usr/bin pid = 4113 KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/plasmashell  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Try to run plasmashell in terminal. See also [link](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/start-menu-dissapeared/10487).

Comment: Running plasmashell gives me a segfault (exact output added to main post).  In the link you provided, this requires me to be able to be able to right click on the desktop, which I cannot.

Comment: Some more checks: [post1](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/a1cu6y/help_rightclicking_on_desktop_doesnt_show_context/), also [post2](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/abrjpg/kde_reset_to_default_no_right_click_empty/).

Comment: @harrymc Neither of those work.  I can't right-click anywhere at all on my desktop.  it's as if it's not there - I can only right click on the applications that I run from terminal via yakuke.

Comment: Was any update done to the system? If yes, see the approach in [downgrade all packages to a specific date](https://www.ostechnix.com/downgrade-packages-specific-date-arch-linux/) and see if you can adapt it to your setup.

Comment: I think the most recent thing I've done was set up a network printer over the CUPS Web interface.  Oddly, every time I printed, my entire screen flashed a lighter colour and froze until I restarted - though the pages printed.  I'm thinking it may have something to do with this..

Comment: Try to undo that install and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something on the computer that used to work suddenly stops working,
the first question should be "What has changed?".

The problem can be hardware, but software is usually the cause.
One should look first for any of the following:

- New product installed, or existing product updated
- Driver update
- Operating system upgrade.

If any of the above happened just before the problem started, the immediate test
is to undo the change. In the case of a driver, it should be uninstalled from
the device *and* from the operating system (or it will return upon reboot).

After undoing the change, reboot and test if the problem has gone away.
In case of success, this update should be blocked from coming back again.

In this post, the problem was caused by the installation of a network printer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by a network printer that I added to CUPS via the web interface. I accessed the web interface by http://localhost:631/ and deleted the printer that I added.  I am not sure why this specifically caused plasmashell to crash, but this fixed the segmentation fault.  I have opened a bug at https://bugs.kde.org/ for this to find the root cause.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT they are the bounty giver too, they can't get any of it unless it is reversed by a mod.

Comment: Not me either but comments deleted...