# Determine correct lastScreen values for panels in plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, kde-plasma-5

I have a laptop that I plug into a docking station on a daily basis. And almost every time, I need to modify my `plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`, then do a plasma restart `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart plasmashell`. As per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/946206/kde-plasma-5-no-taskbar-and-cant-right-click-desktop).

The problem I have, is that at one point, I could mostly automate this since typically I just needed to toggle the lastScreen value between 2 and 3 for one panel. Sadly something has changed in the last couple of months, and now, I need to modify lastScreen for both panels for my 2 external monitors, and the numbers can range from 0-4.

What I'd like to know, is if there is some way to determine which monitor is currently set to which number. Ideally it would be a command line value I could read programmatically to feed into a script. But even just a way to show the number on each monitor would save me time trying multiple combinations.

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.

For info currently `xrandr --listmonitors` shows:

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +DP-1-2 1920/518x1200/324+0+0  DP-1-2
 1: +DP-2-2 1920/518x1200/324+1920+0  DP-2-2
```

while my plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc currently shows for DP-1-2

```
[Containments][54]
activityId=
formfactor=2
immutability=1
lastScreen=0
location=4
plugin=org.kde.panel
wallpaperplugin=org.kde.image
```

and shows for DP-2-2

```
[Containments][63]
activityId=
formfactor=2
immutability=1
lastScreen=4
location=4
plugin=org.kde.panel
wallpaperplugin=org.kde.image
```

Answer (score 3):

Check `~/.config/plasmashellrc`, it should have a `[ScreenConnectors]` section that maps `lastScreen` numbers to `xrandr` names:

```
[ScreenConnectors]
0=DisplayPort-0
1=DisplayPort-1
```

Those `DisplayPort` names match my `xrandr` output:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DisplayPort-0 1920/518x1200/324+0+0  DisplayPort-0
 1: +DisplayPort-1 1920/518x1200/324+1920+0  DisplayPort-1
```

(I'm on Kubuntu 20.04)

---

If you're hand-editing `plasmashellrc` save the file & do a [quick](https://superuser.com/questions/933890)

```
kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
```

...to restart Plasma reasonably cleanly.